# Calculating SVG Gradient Coordinates for Angled Repeating Lines

Tags: svg

I'm trying to generate a parallelogram in SVG with repeating lines that are along the same angle as the left and right sides of the polygon. Something like this:

[image: parallelogram]

I got the repeating gradient to work, but I can't get the angle of the lines right. They're skewed from the angle of the bounding parallelogram:

[image: gradient]

I know I can manipulate the angle based on the (x1, y1) / (x2, y2) attributes of the gradient, but just playing with the numbers isn't doing it for me. How can I calculate which values to use for these attributes given a known angle?

Here's the SVG code I have right now:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 1680 550" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="StripedGradient" spreadMethod="repeat" x1="0%" x2="1%" y1="0%" y2="1%">
            <stop stop-color="yellow" offset="0%" />
            <stop stop-color="yellow" offset="15%" />
            <stop stop-color="transparent" offset="15%" />
            <stop stop-color="transparent" offset="100%" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <polygon fill="url(#StripedGradient)" points="0 550, 415 145, 610 145, 195 550" />
</svg>
```

This angle currently works out to be just under 45deg (44.301...), but the value could change at the discretion of the designer, so...

(I'm really new to SVG, as in I knew it existed, but I had never written inline SVG by hand until today.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly simple approach would be to define your gradient as a horizontal stripe. Then if you also use `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`, you can use a `gradientTransform` to set your angle.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 750 550" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="StripedGradient" spreadMethod="repeat"
                        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                        x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20"
                        gradientTransform="rotate(-44.301)">
            <stop stop-color="red" offset="0%" />
            <stop stop-color="red" offset="15%" />
            <stop stop-color="transparent" offset="15%" />
            <stop stop-color="transparent" offset="100%" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <polygon fill="url(#StripedGradient)" points="0 550, 415 145, 610 145, 195 550" />
</svg>
```